# Problem in unmounting a disk image with a script... but not manually!

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, umount

It is my first experience in writing shell scripts and something curious is happening. I'm working on an embedded system and I wanted my script test5.sh placed in the /root folder of the guest system to mount the first partition of an eMMC card image, perform a test on it, remove the files created by test1, kill the process still accessing the card [to avoid resource busy, in my case there's always just one single process from fuser command] and finally I want to unmount the card itself. This is what I wrote:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ../dev
e2fsck mmcblk0p1
mount -t auto mmcblk0p1 ../mnt
cd ../mnt
./../bin/test1
rm file*
variable=$(fuser -m /mnt)
echo $variable
kill -9 $variable
echo "Before the problem"
umount /mnt
echo "After the problem"
```

The problem is that the last umount command is not executed as I can check from the terminal output:

```
# ./test5.sh 
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
mmcblk0p1: clean, 11/117360 files, 7386/468990 blocks
STARTED
random: nonblocking pool is initialized
ENDED
647
Killed
# mount
[...]
mmcblk0p1 on /mnt type ext2 (rw,relatime,errors=continue)
```

At this point if I manually send the last command in the script:

```
umount /mnt
```

the operation is successfully accomplished [I checked with mount]. Why is the last line of the script "invisible"? I can't find the missing point. How to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help

---

***edit***

---

I'm beginning to think that the umount /command is not executed because of the process I kill; when manually running:

```
lsof /mnt
```

to have a verbose output instead of fuser -m /mnt [which returns just 640] the output is:

```
# lsof /mnt
1   /bin/busybox    /dev/console
1   /bin/busybox    /dev/console
1   /bin/busybox    /dev/console
624 /bin/busybox    /dev/null
624 /bin/busybox    /dev/null
624 /bin/busybox    /dev/null
624 /bin/busybox    socket:[747]
624 /bin/busybox    /tmp/messages
625 /bin/busybox    /dev/null
625 /bin/busybox    /dev/null
625 /bin/busybox    /dev/null
625 /bin/busybox    socket:[751]
640 /bin/busybox    /dev/ttyAMA0
640 /bin/busybox    /dev/ttyAMA0
640 /bin/busybox    /dev/ttyAMA0
640 /bin/busybox    /dev/tty
```

What it seems to me is that killing the process with pid 640 [the one who gives the resource busy, ttyAMA0 is the serial port of my embedded system] means the death of the rest of the script [even the two final echo lines are skipped]. And when manually executing the kill line I have to login again while when launching the script this doesn't happen. Now it would be nice to know the reason and the fix

Comment: Try `sleep 0.5` before `umount`. It may be a "rare" problem

Comment: Your script is good but you will have to leave the directory /mnt before unmounting the device, i have added an answer with a minor change to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not unmount the device during script because of the fact that your script contains
 `cd ../mnt` which means the current working directory is the same where your device has been mounted thus change your script as :

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ../dev
e2fsck mmcblk0p1
mount -t auto mmcblk0p1 ../mnt
cd ../mnt
./../bin/test1
rm file*
variable=$(fuser -m /mnt)
echo $variable
kill -9 $variable
cd ~
sudo umount -f /mnt
```

Comment: If this solves your problem don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of the text, which means "I accept the answer"

Comment: neither the "sleep 0.5" nor the "cd .." lines could make it work. I'm more and more confused about

Comment: i have edited my answer again, try the new script and reply what happens.

Comment: I tried again and it still doesn't work... honestly after these attempts I don't think it's a folder problem [and sudo does not change the result]

Comment: sorry i had written command for forced mount not unmount, edited, check it

Comment: it didn't work... I edited the answer to give other food for thought... thank you very much @faizan!